# Как пропарсить сайт с авторизацией?

Tags: c#, парсер, password

нужно пропарсить https://dnevnik.mos.ru/manage/student_journal/, который требует авторизации
С парсингом валюты или других сайтов, открытых без авторизации - это то понятно, но что делать если нужно парсить подобное?
через что это можно реализовать?)
буду рад любым объяснениям

Comment: Передавать логин и пароль/токен в запросе?

Comment: тобиж вы о подобном? http/блалалалбал/login+password

Comment: тогда, как ее оттуда выудить?

Comment: Я не в курсе, как там это работает. Посмотрите, в каком виде после авторизации запросы посылаются. Повторите тоже самое из кода.

Answer (score 1):

Если там стоит капча(особенно ReCapcha):

1. Открывать браузер вроде CEF что бы пользователь залогинился вручную.
2. Вытягнуть из CEF куки
3. Закрыть CEF и дальше работать с куками. При чем на много сессий. Просто через какой-то нюгет для работы с REST.

Если капча не стоит:

1. Спарсить реквест логина и повторять его с подстановкой логина и пароля при помощи любой библиотеки для работы с REST.
2. сохранить куки и токен
3. дальше работать с ними програмно и доставать текст хтмл-а при помощи все того же REST.